# Sugar orm update bug

Tags: android, sugarorm

I'm new to data base and therefore I preferred to use `Sugar ORM` instead of `SQLite` in my android project.

But there is a problem. whenever I use the `SugarRecord.update()` method to update and existing record all records are replaced by the new record.

Could anyone please help me with an answer?

```
@Override
    public void updateInDataBase(Bookmark bookmark, long id) {
        History oldHistory = History.findById(History.class, id);

        LogManager.d("owntest oldHistory In update  " + oldHistory);
        oldHistory.setLastUpdateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        oldHistory.update();
    }
```

Comment: It's worth to say that if I just replace .update() with .save() every thing works fine !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have found a bug that is described here.
https://github.com/chennaione/sugar/issues/633. It may be the case, that the author intended this for some reason, though I am not sure. Nevertheless, you can and probably should use the save() method as suggested by the official docs: http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html#usage

Comment: I believe that `.update()` was originally intended as an "Update All" function, but is just poorly named.